# Accessing current class' version of a function in php

Tags: php, javascript, class

I'm trying to develop a system in PHP that can generate JS "classes", and I have an implementation that works.  The problem I'm running into surrounds multiple inclusion of these JS classes; my code will print out the JS class every time it's needed, and I want it to print out only the first time.

My current solution to this problems is inelegant; it requires the PHP class developer to explicitly call a function which will check if the JS class has yet been included.  e.g.:

```
public function getJSClass() {
//:: Call Parent
$js = parent::getJSClass();

//:: Add Current Class
if ($this->classNeeded('SearchAndManageDataManipulator')) {
    $js .= "
        //|| Class: SearchAndManageDataManipulator
        /**
         * Base class for applications which feature a search and results control
         * as the central element of the application.  Such applications generally
         * specialize in handling multiple records at once.
         */
        function SearchAndManageDataManipulator() {

            // ...

        }
        SearchAndManageDataManipulator.inheritsDM(WindowedDataManipulator);
    ";
}

//:: Return
return $js;
}
```

I'd like to isolate this checking from the class developer, to make it something like the following:

```
public function getJSClass() {
return "
        //|| Class: SearchAndManageDataManipulator
        /**
         * Base class for applications which feature a search and results control
         * as the central element of the application.  Such applications generally
         * specialize in handling multiple records at once.
         */
        function SearchAndManageDataManipulator() {

            // ...

        }
        SearchAndManageDataManipulator.inheritsDM(WindowedDataManipulator);
    ";
}
```

So, I'd like to create a function which calls getJSClass iff the class is needed, as well as any parent getJSClass()es; the function will need the name of the class, to check if it has already been included.  That class name is set by overriding another function, jsClassName(); however calling jsClassName() will always return the class name of the class lowest in the class heirarchy, because it's the latest overridden version of the function.

If a parent class is calling getJSClass(), I need it to be able to check if the class name in jsClassName() has been included yet.  But it can't be the version of jsClassName() which has been overridden for the lowest class, it needs to be the version defined in the parent class.

Is there any way to access the "current" class' version of a function?  By current, I mean the class in which the current function was defined.  That way, as we move up the parent:: chain, jsClassName will reflect the class name in question.

Comment: Wow, I got distracted at work, and completely forgot that I'd asked this question :-).  Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array to keep track of your class chain and only add a class if it doesn't exist for key `jsClassName()`:

```
public function getJSClass()
{
    $chain = parent::getJSClass();

    return $chain + array(
        $this->jsClassName() => "implementation here",
    );
}
```

The topmost implementation would be slightly different to initialize the array:

```
public function getJSClass()
{
    return array(
        $this->jsClassName() => "implementation",
    );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is an implementation similar to what I currently have; $this->classNeeded() keeps track of previous inclusions by storing them in an array.  This solution still requires that the class developer put all of this extra code into the class definition function; I'm looking for a construct where they can simply write a function that returns "implementation here", and the wrapper function takes care of all the extra stuff.

Comment: also, AFAIK calling $this->jsClassName() will always return the class name of the instance, even if called in parent:: versions of getJSClass()